# Possible Riemann's Hypothesis proof?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, riemann-hypothesis, euler-mascheroni-constant, distribution-of-primes

First of all, I imagine it will not be correct, just because of its simplicity, but I would also want to know why, as I can't find any mistake on it.

The "proof" would be based on convining two main theorems/formulae. The first one, would be [this one](http://aimath.org/WWN/rh/articles/html/99a/) , due to Nicolas, where it is stated that RH would hold iff:

$$\frac{N_k}{\phi{(N_k)}} > e^{\gamma} \ln{(\ln{(N_k)})}$$

holded for every $k$ being $N_k$ the primorial of order $k$ and $\phi{(N_k)}$ its Euler's Totient function.

Then, my main aim here will be to prove that formula for every $k$. To do that, I will use this other theorem:

$$ \prod_{p \le n} \frac{p}{p-1} >  e^{\gamma}(\ln{n})(1-\frac{1}{2(\ln{n})^{2}})$$

Taken from "Approximate Formulas for Some Functions of Prime Numbers" ([link](https://oeis.org/A000720/a000720.html)), Theorem 8 (3.28).

As, in this case, $\frac{N_k}{\phi{(N_k)}} = \prod_{p \le p_k} \frac{p}{p-1}$, we can try to see if this holds:

$$e^{\gamma}(\ln{p_k})(1-\frac{1}{2(\ln{p_k})^{2}})>e^{\gamma} \ln{\ln{N_k}}$$

Hence

$$\ln{p_k}-\frac{1}{2\ln{p_k}}>\ln{\ln{N_k}}$$

For it to be more clear, we can change $\ln{N_k}$ by $\theta{(k)}$ (Chebyshev's First Function) so that

$$\ln{p_k}-\frac{1}{2\ln{p_k}}>\ln{\theta{(k)}}$$

From there, we could easily get to

$$\frac{1}{2\ln{p_k}}<\ln{\frac{p_k}{\theta{(k)}}}$$

And, with the bounds of Theorems 3 (3.12) and 4 (3.15), we get

$$\frac{1}{2\ln{p_k}}<\ln{\frac{\ln{k}}{1+ \frac{1}{2\ln{k}}}}$$

What would be true for every big enought k, meaning that

$$\frac{N_k}{\phi{(N_k)}} > e^{\gamma} \ln{(\ln{(N_k)})}$$

holds, and, with so, RH.

Is this correct?
Why would/would not it prove the RH?

Thank you!

**Edit** thanks to Jyrki Lahtonen

Comment: I don't understand your question, try to make it readable. And there is no elementary proof of the Lagarias/Robin criterion.

Comment: My question is just where is the error in what I am doing. Thanks

Comment: Assuming the Riemann hypothesis and you get some tight approximations of the functions involved, for example $\sum_{p < x} \frac{1}{p} = \ln \ln x + B+\mathcal{O}(x^{-1/2+\epsilon})$, $\sum_{p < x} \ln p = x+\mathcal{O}(x^{1/2+\epsilon})$, $ \sum_{p < x} \ln(1-\frac{1}{p}) = C- \ln \ln x + \mathcal{O}(x^{-1/2+\epsilon})$ and so on. This way you can see if what you are writing is a nonsense, and if it is tautologic. And again, I don't understand what you wrote in your question, try to restate it **clearly**

Comment: FYI: You get a subscript by prepending it with an underscore. So for example `$a_{k+1}$` gives $a_{k+1}$. I added some of those, but didn't want to make too many changes (sorry about not asking right away whether you meant $N_k$ instead of $Nk$).

Comment: To be clear "with the bounds of Theorems 3 (3.13) and 4 (3.16)," means that you are using some theorems you don't understand. And I don't see how a bound for $1/\ln p_k$ would help for bounding $\prod_{p < x} (1-\frac{1}{p})$. So again, write only the necessary the steps **clearly**, with the main step made obvious (and separate what is comparatively trivial : $p_k \sim k \ln k$, $\sum_{p < x} \frac{1}{p} \sim \ln \ln x$, i.e. the Mertens theorems and the prime number theorem, from the less trivial things)

Comment: and this is obviously not true : $$\frac{1}{2\ln{p_k}}<\ln{\frac{\ln{k}+\ln{\ln{k}}}{1+ \frac{1}{\ln{k}}}}$$
since the RHS $\sim -\ln(1+\frac{1}{\ln k})\sim \frac{-1}{\ln k}$, while the LHS $\sim \frac{1}{2\ln k}$

Comment: $\frac{1}{2\ln{p_k}}<\ln{\frac{\ln{k}+\ln{\ln{k}}}{1+ \frac{1}{\ln{k}}}}$ should be $\frac{1}{2\ln{p_k}}<\ln{\frac{\ln{k}+\ln{\ln{k}}}{1- \frac{1}{\ln{k}}}}$ by the equations you cited.

Comment: @user1952009 But as $\ln{k}+\ln{\ln{k}}>1+\frac{1}{\ln{k}}$, $$\ln{\frac{\ln{k}+\ln{\ln{k}}}{1+\frac{1}{\ln{k}}}}$$ will tend to grow whereas $$\frac{1}{2\ln{x}}$$ won't

Comment: @user361424 Bad quote. It was (3.15). Thank you

Comment: don't waste our time with nonsense formulas. read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens%27_theorems where everything you need to know is explained

Comment: @user346773 No, I think you wanted 3.16, since now you've put an upper bound on the denominator, when you probably want to use a lower bound for the denominator and an upper for the numerator to ensure the RHS be greater than in the previous step.  (And I'm certain you wanted 3.13, not 3.12.)

Comment: @user361424 But wouldn't I have to use the lower bound for the numerator and the upper bound for the denominaror to ensure the inequality holds even in the worst of the cases?

Comment: @user346773 Ah - I forgot that the inequality was something to be proven rather than an established fact.  Sorry.  Because of that, though, you should take out the log log n in the numerator.

Comment: @user361424 Oops, thanks. My mistake. Luckily, the inequality continues holding in spite of that

Comment: Oh, um, also, this doesn't affect it either, but (3.15) says $1+\frac{1}{2\log x}$.

Comment: Another thing - wouldn't $\ln N_k$ be $\theta(p_k)$, not $\theta(k)$?

Comment: @user361424 https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_function .Here, in the "Relations to primorials" section, it states that $$\theta(k)=\ln(N_k)$$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47810/discussion-between-user361424-and-user346773).

Comment: @user361424 That's totally true, but I think that's because of that Wikipedia's formula may be wrong. Taking the definition of $\theta(k)$ from here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevFunctions.html (the formula baes on $\pi(k)$ ) would fit perfectly in what I wrote, as $\pi(N_k)=k$ and then $(p_1)(p_2)(p_3)(...)(p_k)=N_k$

Comment: The definition you linked also says explicitly $\theta(x) = x\#$.  $\pi(N_k)$ is in fact quite a bit higher than k, since it's all primes less than $N_k$, which will include many that aren't factors - for instance, $\pi(N_3) = \pi(30) = 10$.

Comment: @user361424 Oh, ok, understood, so sorry. Thank you!

Comment: @user361424 One more question. Then, would $\theta(14)=\theta(15)$ as $\pi(14)=\pi(15)$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With $p_1, p_2, \ldots$ being a list of primes in increasing order
we have $N_k = p_1 p_2 \cdots p_k$ for the primorial. Therefore
$$\frac{N_k}{\phi(N_k)}=\prod_{p\le p_k}\frac{p}{p-1}.$$

Hence the lower bound is only
$$
\frac{N_k}{\phi(N_k)} > e^\gamma \log p_k \left(1 - \frac1{2 \log^2 p_k}\right),
$$
which does not work for the remaining argument.